# Preload div content while showing loader

Tags: jquery, html, preload

this seems to be hundred times answered question, but I can't find a working solution.

I've got this code:

```
<script>
  $("#content div").hide();
  $("#loader").show();

  $("#content div").load("file.html", function () {

    $("#loader").fadeOut('slow', function() {

      $("#content div").fadeIn('slow');

    });

  });
</script>

<html>
  <div id="content">
    <div></div>
    <img src="loader.gif" />
  </div>
</html>
```

As far as I'm concerned the stuff that is inside the load function should happen after the file.html is loaded, but it hides the loader image and shows content div (in this case huge image, but it can be anything) and it still loads this content - the loading process is not finished. Thanks.

Comment: If you intend to show your content after the **image** has loaded the you must preload **the image** not the html that renders it.

Comment: But how do I preload image before I load the file that includes that image? Other stuff than image might be included in this html file.

Comment: It all comes down to when your ajax load is finished. It is finished when your file.html is loaded, not when your image contained in the html has finished to loaded. As Oybek said, preload your image or just load your image into a container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the following library. I don't remember where I took it from.

```
    /* Image loader */
    function addListener(element, type, expression, bubbling) {
        bubbling = bubbling || false;
        if (window.addEventListener) { // Standard
            element.addEventListener(type, expression, bubbling);
            return true;
        } else if (window.attachEvent) { // IE
            element.attachEvent('on' + type, expression);
            return true;
        } else return false;
    }


    var ImageLoader = function (url) {
        this.url = url;
        this.image = null;
        this.loadEvent = null;
    };

    ImageLoader.prototype = {
        load: function () {
            this.image = document.createElement('img');
            var url = this.url;
            var image = this.image;
            var loadEvent = this.loadEvent;
            addListener(this.image, 'load', function (e) {
                if (loadEvent != null) {
                    loadEvent(url, image);
                }
            }, false);
            this.image.src = this.url;
        },
        getImage: function () {
            return this.image;
        }
    };
    /* End of image loader */
```

Include the above script. Then you can simply use it as follows.

```
var loader = new ImageLoader("/Path/MyImage.jpg");
// define your 'onreadystatechange'
loader.loadEvent = function(url, imageAsDom) {
    // do what you need
}
loader.load();
```

Comment: Great response, I think the best. Even though I gotta say everyone helped me here to get the idea of what is going on, because that's what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

#### Description

Because `.load()` uses ajax, the right way to display a "loading" indicator is to use jQuery's `ajaxStart` and `ajaxComplete` events.

> **jQuery.ajaxStart()** Register a handler to be called when the first Ajax request begins. This is an Ajax Event.
>
> **jQuery.ajaxComplete()** Register a handler to be called when Ajax requests complete. This is an Ajax Event.

#### Sample

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
     $("#loader").show();
});

$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
     $("#loader").fadeOut('slow');
});
```

#### More Information

- [jQuery.ajaxStart()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxstart/)
- [jQuery.ajaxComplete()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/)

Comment: neat, I'll have to remember those two.

Answer (score 0):

Loader needed to be an id but this is better way to format your code.

```
<html>
  <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#content div").hide();
      $("#loader").show();

      $("#content div").load("file.html", function () {
        $("#loader").fadeOut('slow', function() {
          $("#content").fadeIn('slow');
        });
      });
    });
  </script>  
  </head>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <img id="loader" src="loader.gif" />
    <div id="content"></div>
  </div>
</html>
```

Comment: It was just for sample to get the idea, I've got it coded differently anyway.

Comment: If you say something isn't working you should show us exactly how you code it otherwise we may give you bad response.

Comment: Well I think everyone got the idea.

Comment: But I'm sorry I've wasted your time responding my post. I'll keep that in mind next time.